# Grails Createcriteria for subquery

Tags: regex, grails

How to use createCriteria for subQuery . 
My HQL is like this :

def lists = List.executeQuery("FROM List cl WHERE cl.brand_id in (SELECT b.id FROM Brand b WHERE cl.brand_id=b.id AND b.brand_name rLIKE '^[0123456789].*')")

Please tell how can we write this using Createcriteria ??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Hibernate doesn't support rlike or regexp feature (see http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3404) 
But Grails does !!

For that you need to used createCriteria (and not executeQuery)
Based on this discussion http://n4.nabble.com/Using-rlike-in-a-gorm-query-td1391934.html and on http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3481, your solution will be:

```
def c = List.createCriteria(); 
results = c { 
        rlike("name", "^[0123456789].*") 
}
```

Attention: it might work only on MySQL and Oracle

Comment: Hi, thanks fabien.
But how to use createCriteria for subQuery .
My final sql is like this :



def lists = List.executeQuery("FROM List cl WHERE cl.brand_id in (SELECT b.id  FROM Brand b WHERE cl.brand_id=b.id AND b.brand_name rLIKE '^[0123456789].*')")

How can we change this in to createcriteria ?
Please help me ..

Answer (score 1):

When querying on a domain object's property you need to make a block in the criteria with the name of the property. Something like:

```
def criteria = List.createCriteria(); 
def results = criteria {
    brand {
        rlike("name", "^[0123456789].*") 
    }
}
```

See also the "Querying Associations" section in the [Grails GORM criteria docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4.2%20Criteria)